# Magento delete item from cart redirection on custom controller

Tags: magento, module

Got a problem with redirection when remove item from cart on custom controller. I am writing a module that uses it's own route. When I delete item on magento pages like product page, catalog, etc. redirection works fine, it give me same page. But when I delete item on my custom module route, it redirects me on home page. 
I found redirect function in CartController.php

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
```

Magentowiki says that '*' will use current module, controller or action in use. 
Should I register my route somewhere else (besides config.xml of my module), so redirect function could understand it? Or maybe i have to use some event observer, check if current page is my module and then use my own redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*',array('_current'=>true)));
```